# Drag text to address bar to search

Tags: firefox, search, address-bar

Is there any way to enable functionality to drag text to the Firefox Address bar to search Google? I want Firefox to work like Chrome, in that respect.

From [LifeHacker](http://www.lifehacker.com.au/2011/03/open-new-tabs-by-dragging-links-and-text-to-chromes-tab-bar/):

> But what most people probably don’t
>   know is that it works with text, as
>   well. Dragging the words “Digital
>   Painting” to the tab bar opens up a
>   new tab that immediately performs a
>   search for those two words (typically
>   in Google, but it uses whatever your
>   default search is set to).

I'm comfortable with working in `about:config`, and I'd rather not have to install an add-on, if possible.

---

Note: I don't like to use the Search box, so I've removed it. I want FF to be as Chrome as possible with a single integrated "omnibox" (in this respect).

Comment: I don't think there is without using the search box. Is there a reason you're not using Chrome? :D

Comment: @Nano I do use Chrome >90% of the time on Windows. But for some reason, Firefox seems a bit more nicely integrated for Ubuntu than Chrome, so I might be using it more and more on Ubuntu. (Chrome still pwns for Windows, though. :) )

Comment: ) I see that's cool ahaha.

Answer (score 3):

The Firefox equivalent of this is to select the word or phrase. Then drag & drop the text into search field in the upper right corner of the browser.

This will perform a search on the highlighted text in the tab you're currently in, through the last used search engine selected.

Comment: I don't use the Search box. (I've removed it.)